# MySQL Index calculation?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a Query that could do with optimization if possible as it's taking 15 seconds to run.

It is querying a large db with approx 1000000 records and is slowed down by grouping by hour (which is derived from DATE_FORMAT()).

I indexed all relevant fields in all the tables which improved the performance significantly but I don't know how to or if it's even possible to create an index for the hour group since it's not a field...

I do realise the dataset is very large but I'd like to know if I have any options.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

```
SELECT  `id`,
    tbl1.num,
    name,
    DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%x-%v') AS wknum,
    DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
    DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%H') as hour,
    IF(code<>0,codedescription,'') AS status,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`timeblock`))/60 AS time, 
    SUM(`distance`) AS distance, 
    SUM(`distance`)/(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`timeblock`))/60) AS speed
FROM  `tbl1`
LEFT JOIN `tbl2` ON tbl1.code = tbl2.code 
LEFT JOIN `tbl3` ON tbl1.status = tbl3.status 
LEFT JOIN `tbl4` ON tbl1.conditionnum = tbl4.conditionnum 
LEFT JOIN `tbl5` ON tbl1.num = edm_mc_list.num
WHERE `timestamp`>'2013-07-28 00:00:00'
GROUP BY `num`,DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%H'),`mcstatus`
```

Comment: Is it better if you `GROUP BY num, hour, mcstatus`? MySQL might be repeating the `DATE_FORMAT()`, which is unnecessary since you're already doing it in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: But the general answer is that it's not possible to index a calculated value like that.

Comment: Mysql will be using the index of `timestamp` for `hour`

Comment: @Barmar No same result unfortunately and it looks like I'm out of luck with this one then... But on the bright side I now know you can use an alias in the group by! Don't know why I didn't try that!

Comment: Stupid question but do you need to use a left join? A left join would select all rows from the table on the left side. Using a inner join would substantially reduce the number of rows. Just a suggestion I dont have too much context on why you need all the data from those tabls.

Comment: @doovers: The output from an `EXPLAIN` would help identify if suitable indexes are being used for those JOINS. The columns in the SELECT list aren't qualified, so we can't tell which table each column is being retrieved from. We can guess that `codedescription` is being returned from tbl2, or tbl4, but we're just guessing. The grouping by hour is going to require a "Using filesort" operation, since MySQL can't optimize that with an index. (A separate `hour` column, included in an appropriate index, might speed things up.)

Comment: @Namphibian unfortunately I do need the left joins as I'm pulling in data from other tables to supplement the main data in tbl1

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for the tip I'll give the explain a go and see. I think that adding the hour column is probably what I'll have to do though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL generally can’t use indexes on columns unless the columns are
isolated in the query. **Isolating** the column means it should not be part of an expression or be inside a function in the query.

Solutions:

1-You can store hour separate from `timestamp` column. for example you can store it by both `before insert` and `before update` triggers.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_hour`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl1`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF NEW.`timestamp` != OLD.`timestamp` THEN
       SET NEW.`hour` = DATE_FORMAT( NEW.`timestamp`,'%H')
     END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_hour`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl1`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     SET NEW.`hour` = DATE_FORMAT( NEW.`timestamp`,'%H')
 END;
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

2-If you can use MariaDB, you can use MariaDB [virtual columns](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/virtual-columns/).